# Scheme - returning first n-elements of an array

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a function in Scheme that returns the first n elements in a list. I'm want to do that without loops, just with this basic structure below.

What I've tried is:

```
(define n-first
(lambda (lst n)
(if (or(empty? lst) (= n 0))
    (list)
    (append (car lst) (n-first (cdr lst) (- n 1))))))
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
append: contract violation
expected: list?
given: 'in
```

I've tried to debug it and it looks that the tail of the recursion crashes it, meaning, just after returning the empty list the program crashes.

When replacing "append" operator with "list" I get:

Input: (n-first '(the cat in the hat) 3)

Output:

```
'(the (cat (in ())))
```

But I want to get an appended list.

Comment: What you want is `cons` in place of `append`. `append` combines "lists", not non-list elements, and `(car lst)` produces the first element within `lst`, which is why you're getting the error noted.

Answer (score 0):

A list that looks like `(1 2 3)` i constructed like `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))` or if you're more familiar with `cons` `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`. Thus `(list 1 2 3))` does exactly that under the hood. This is crucial information in order to be good at procedures that works on them. Notice that the first `cons` cannot be applied before the `(cons 2 (cons 3 '()))` is finished so a list is always created from end to beginning. Also a list is iterated from beginning to end.

So you want:

```
(define lst '(1 2 3 4 5))

(n-first lst 0) ; == '()
(n-first lst 1) ; == (cons (car lst) (n-first (- 1 1) (cdr lst)))
(n-first lst 2) ; == (cons (car lst) (n-first (- 2 1) (cdr lst)))
```

`append` works like this:

```
(define (append lst1 lst2)
  (if (null? lst1)
      lst2
      (cons (car lst1)
            (append (cdr lst1) lst2))))
```

`append` is O(n) time complexity so if you use that each iteration of `n` parts of a list then you get O(n^2). For small lists you won't notice it but even a medium sized lists of a hundred thousand elements you'll notice `append` uses about 50 times longer to complete than the `cons` one and for large lists you don't want to wait for the result since it grows exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

try so

```
(define first-n
  (lambda (l)
    (lambda (n)
      ((lambda (s)
         (s s l n (lambda (x) x)))
       (lambda (s l n k)
         (if (or (zero? n)
                 (null? l))
             (k '())
             (s s (cdr l) (- n 1)
                (lambda (rest)
                  (k (cons (car l) rest))))))))))

(display ((first-n '(a b c d e f)) 4))
(display ((first-n '(a b)) 4))
```

In scheme you must compute mentally the types of each expression, as it does not have a type checker/ type inference included.